# Background Worker and Timer in System Tray App C#

Tags: c#

This is an incredibly simple task tray app - using `ApplicationContext` and a few guides I found online.

The purpose of the app is to query a small `REST` `API` and show a message box to the user on a given result. I need to essentially have the `API` query in a background loop, running every 10 seconds or something similar. This is to report on data that I've made accessible via another service.

I've done some reading and it seems a `BackgroundWorker` and Timer is an appropriate option, but I'm lost on where to go next. How exactly can I achieve this? I initially tried adding a `while(true)` loop to the `TaskTrayApplicationContext` but it just created an infinite loop whereby you couldn't do anything else with the app.

```
namespace TaskTrayApplication
{
public class TaskTrayApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
    NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    Configuration configWindow = new Configuration();

    public TaskTrayApplicationContext()
    {
        MenuItem configMenuItem = new MenuItem("Configuration", new EventHandler(ShowConfig));
        MenuItem exitMenuItem = new MenuItem("Exit", new EventHandler(Exit));

       notifyIcon.Icon = TaskTrayApplication.Properties.Resources.AppIcon;
        notifyIcon.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(ShowMessage);
        notifyIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[] { configMenuItem, exitMenuItem });
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    }


    void ShowMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Only show the message if the settings say we can.
        if (TaskTrayApplication.Properties.Settings.Default.ShowMessage)
            MessageBox.Show("This is the Serenity TaskTray Agent.");
    }

    void ShowConfig(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If we are already showing the window meerly focus it.
        if (configWindow.Visible)
            configWindow.Focus();
        else
            configWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    void Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // We must manually tidy up and remove the icon before we exit.
        // Otherwise it will be left behind until the user mouses over.
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;

        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

}

And the Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TaskTrayApplication
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            // Instead of running a form, we run an ApplicationContext.
            Application.Run(new TaskTrayApplicationContext());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'I've done some reading and it seems a BackgroundWorker and Timer is an appropriate option, but I'm lost on where to go next' welp - why don't you try implementing those solutions if you think they could work? what exactly are you asking for in this question?

Comment: I suppose I am looking for an example, or some assistance with the code itself. Examples online relate primarily to forms, and this is an ApplicationContext. I'm not sure where exactly I would define my loop, my BackgroundWorker or my Timer. C# is a very new language to me.

Comment: okay but SO is more of a Q and A site - not a 'look at this - what do you think' thats more for forums (e.g. reddit) or perhaps the stackoverflow c# chat. So your answer should contain consice, concrete questions - the ones you mention in the comment are some good examples of great question. Why don't you try to google those questions and try things yourself? then when you're stuck you can always come back here and ask 'a better question'. (not trying to push your down or anything like that - but that will give you better results)

Comment: I have googled, but have been unable to find any examples with relation to an ApplicationContext and not a form, hence my posting here, as my experience with this language is very limited, it's harder to piece stuff together.

Comment: i feel you - ill try and formulate an answer.

Comment: I really appreciate that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213233/discussion-between-pnp-and-sommmen).

Answer (score 2):

Threading is hard, concurrency is hard. Background worker and System.Timers are both constructs that run in their own thread.

winforms won't allow for interaction between threads that own a control (read: that created a control) and threads that don't. This is a whole subject apart i wont get into now - theres good stuff to read out there why this is and how to go about it: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/18/multithreading-in-winforms.aspx

There are tools to help, one is the dispatchertimer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netcore-3.1

This is a special timer that instead of its own thread, schedules tasks on the main thread. The main thread in a winforms application handles the drawing of controls, showing of the different windows etc. e.g. this 'owns' all controls.

A sample can be seen on msdn, i adopted it here to show you what you could do:

```
public class TaskTrayApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
    ...


    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

    public TaskTrayApplicationContext()
    {
        ...

        dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }


    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fetch your data via a rest api
        var myData = MyDataFunction();

        // check and show dialog if the data is not okay
        if(myData.Result.Value = 'NOT_OKAY!')
           ShowMessage(this, myData.Result); // or something.
    }

    ...
```

Now since this does not utilize a second thread, this means the main ui thread could be blocked from drawing the windows, reacting to user input etc. because its busy doing work in the timer_tick function. This would for example happen if your rest call takes a long time.

This will make your application freeze and irresponsive. This could be a problem but most likely wont, so lets burn that bridge when we get to it.

Comment: Seemingly, the System.Windows.Threading namespace isn't available, which is apparently the case, it is not available in a Windows Form app.

Comment: @PnP hm.. thats quite possible, i switched to WPF some time ago so i could have mixed some things up. what framework version are you running on?

Comment: Currently, 4.0.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an alternative to this method for WinForms?